# Error with Unity iOS compile: Cross Compilation job Mono.WebBrowser.dll failed

Tags: c#, ios, compilation, compiler-errors, unity-game-engine

have been working on a project intended for iOS deployment. Until recently, we have been building and deploying to our client via webplayer. However, I am now attempting to shift to releasing builds on iOS . But, no matter what I try, when I go to compile the project I receive the following error messages:

```
Cross compilation job Mono.WebBrowser.dll failed.
UnityEngine.UnityException: Failed AOT cross compiler: /Applications/Unity_45/Unity.app/Contents/PlaybackEngines/iOSSupport/Tools/OSX/mono-xcompiler --aot=full,asmonly,nodebug,static,outfile="Mono.WebBrowser.dll.s" "Mono.WebBrowser.dll"  current dir : /Users/admin/Desktop/UI_gg_current/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed
 Env: Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render = '/tmp/launch-7SV8Ex/Render'
LOGNAME = 'admin'
PATH = '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin'
TMPDIR = '/var/folders/7c/s32nkpmx0yvgw4mmw_5vhxx40000gn/T/'
MONO_PATH = '/Users/admin/Desktop/UI_gg_current/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed'
SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/tmp/launch-wpdtRI/Listeners'
USER = 'admin'
GC_DONT_GC = 'yes please'
Apple_Ubiquity_Message = '/tmp/launch-cfnoHv/Apple_Ubiquity_Message'
SHELL = '/bin/bash'
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING = '0x1F5:0:0'
GAC_PATH = '/Users/admin/Desktop/UI_gg_current/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed'
HOME = '/Users/admin'
COMMAND_MODE = 'unix2003'
 result file exists: False. Timed out: False
stdout: 
stderr: 

  at UnityEditor.MonoProcessUtility.RunMonoProcess (System.Diagnostics.Process process, System.String name, System.String resultingFile) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at UnityEditor.MonoCrossCompile.CrossCompileAOT (BuildTarget target, System.String crossCompilerAbsolutePath, System.String assembliesAbsoluteDirectory, CrossCompileOptions crossCompileOptions, System.String input, System.String output, System.String additionalOptions) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at UnityEditor.MonoCrossCompile+JobCompileAOT.ThreadPoolCallback (System.Object threadContext) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

and

```
Error building Player: UnityException: Cross compilation failed.
```

I am using Unity 4.5. To date I have : deleted third party dlls (including xml.linq.dll) , removed any instance of Lambda search operators (=>), and deleted the temp folder because I have seen these approaches used in similar situations (I know some aspects of Linq are not supported in iOS cross compile).

I have looked at similar issues such as this one: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/439367/cross-compilation-failed-csharpdll.html. But, I am so perplexed, because it isn't the CSharp assembly causing my problem (which means it isn't one of my scripts?) I am not sure why it would even be including a WebBrowser.dll for an iOS build. Any help is greatly appreciated, as I feel I have searched far and wide for a resolution with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

See the resolution that for this question [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/729237/error-with-ios-compile-cross-compilation-job-monow.html#answer-729899).